# why is it all the brcypt or crypto hashes comparison are always returning false even for correct password

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, cryptojs

I have managed to use   cryptojs and bcrypt to hash /encrypt all my passwords but failed
to compare the hashes(hashed password in database vs hashed input password) always returning false
so i did more digging  to find out the contents of the hashes and these are the results.

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
function setUserPassword(inputPassword){
    const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex')
  let hashedPassword = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(inputPassword, salt, 1000, 16,'sha512').toString('hex')
   return{ //we shall store them in the database later
     salt: salt,
     hashedPassword: hashedPassword
   }
}
database ====>ac0f74b30c94fedbbd591889c4705607  //works perefectly using the above function

challenge comes when validating the user password.. using this function..
   function validateUserPassword(enteredPassword, dbSalt, dbPassword){

// then checks if this generated hash is equal to user's hash in the database or not 
   let hashInput = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(enteredPassword, dbSalt, 1000,16, 'sha512') //the same as above

   //u must compare the hashed password in the db with hashedInput password
   return hashInput === dbPassword //IF it returns true then they match
}
so i checked the  hashInput and discovered that it was a buffer instead of the string... 
hey hashed input password  <Buffer ac 0f 74 b3 0c 94 fe db bd 59 18 89 c4 70 56 07>

//may nodejs version... v6.11.4 and alo tried using v10.15.0 but all in  the vain.
```

Comment: `let hashInput = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(enteredPassword, dbSalt, 1000,16, 'sha512') //the same as above` is not the same as `.... ..toString('hex')`

Comment: Thank you very much, i shall take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `setUserPassword()` you're creating a hex-encoded string from the buffer returned by the hash function, but you're forgetting to do the same in `validateUserPassword()`. This will fix it:

```
let hashInput = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(enteredPassword, dbSalt, 1000,16, 'sha512').toString('hex')
```

Comment: Thank you, it finally worked and now returns true , let me try to also look at bcrypt example also